How can we call multiple brand for same application in OKTA?
I have created a new brand and added custom domain, but I am not able to call that new brand template in forgot password API.
curl --location --request POST 'https://{host}/api/v1/users/{user_id}/credentials/forgot_password?sendEmail=true' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: SSWS {key}' \
--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=ABC'

I want to call template for new brand that I have created, currently I am calling the above getting the existing OKTA template in email.

what do you receive as a response?

Receiving default OKta template
